# Make a validation for a submit form ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

With the following code i upload images to my server using the form below

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
    <input name="image" type="file" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and also using the following .js code

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
            url: "uploadimage.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
         return false
    });
```

but I need to put rules before you submit out the form and so I need use the validation.

Example:

```
$("#form").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
            url: "uploadimage.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
         return false
    });
    },rules: {
        image: "required"
              },
            messages: {
                image: "image is required"
                      }
 });
```

but this code does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "but this code does not work"

That's because you've put a `.submit()` handler inside of the plugin's `submitHandler`...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#form").submit(function(e) { ....
```

The plugin's `submitHandler` already properly handles the default `submit` event by only firing on button click when the form is valid.

By putting another `.submit()` handler inside, it never fires because the form's only submit event has already occurred.

Remove the extra `.submit()` handler

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        // your options
    });
    return false;
},
```

**Validation DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/8tebdxn4/**

---

Also, if you want to upload files, you'll need the proper `enctype` attribute on your `<form>` tag...

```
<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: @Javiersito Make sure you also do server-side validation. Remember everything on the client is out of your control if the user is malicious.